# C# connecting to another database in the same server

Tags: c#, mysql, phpmyadmin

We are working on a system that requires us to connect to another database, but all the databases are in the same server.  As for now we are connected to the server but with only our own database connected, and it's in a separate class.  Which we then call in the main program, so right now I'm trying to figure out how do i connect to another database? We are also using phpmyadmin to edit the databases.

This one is the class to connect to the database and server:

```
 public DatabaseConnection()
            {
                HOST = "server";
                DB = "DB1"; //our database
                UID = "user";
                PASSWD = "password";
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                string connectionstring;

                connectionstring = "SERVER=" + HOST + ";DATABASE=" +
                DB + ";" + "UID=" + UID + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + PASSWD + ";";

                return connectionstring;
            }
```

This one is the one to connect in the main class:

```
 public void connect()
        {
            mySQLconnection = new MySqlConnection(dbInfo.ToString());
            try
            {
                mySQLconnection.Open();
                this.Text = "[Connected]";
                populateCliendinformation();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                this.Text = "Problem";
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use a new connection with a connection string pointing to the new database.

Comment: You have to show what you have tried.  Show the code you are using to connect to your database (please exclude username/password).  Then show what you are trying to do to reach the other DB.  Without that this is not a good question for the SO format.

Comment: If your user has privileges on the other schema/db then you can switch the mysql context to the other DB with the 'use dbname' statement.  Or access table by using db-name.table-name notation

Comment: There i edited it sorry first time posting here

Comment: the same way you connected to your first database

Comment: Create new connection string with database what you have to access use that connection string where ever you have to connect that database same like you have use